# How to turn on/off iPad screen at specific clock times?

Tags: ipad

I would like my iPad's screen to turn ON every morning at 10AM and turn OFF every evening at 6PM.

Note I do not want the iPad to lock itself at 6PM. I would only like the screen to turn on/off. Switching between the lowest and highest Brightest setting would do fine as well.

I'm on iOS 9.3.5.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much you can do seen as your iPad is 5 major versions behind, and back then, there wasn't any reasonable way to do any kind of automations that would allow for what you need. So, in your case, unless you get a newer iPad, there isn't much you can do.

In the latest version of iOS though, you could use the shortcuts app to create an automation at 10am and 6pm to change the screen brightness.